# PHP: @include_once for dynamically loaded content?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, include

I have this `header.php` which I included in all the pages I need it. I used `@include_once('header.php');` in order to be able to load the page via AJAX into the "container" div of another page without having to worry about it being showed twice. But since both the main page and the loaded page have the header included, the header is showing twice. I thought `include_once` was supposed to not let that happen. What should I do?

Comment: `include_once` ensures that it is only included once in the current running script.  When you load via AJAX, it is another request and it's not taken in to account that it was loaded previously from another script running.

Comment: So there's no way I can make this work the way I want?
The reason I want it to be included in both of the scripts is because people can either go to that page or load it dynamically]

Comment: Exclude the header in the content that is loaded via ajax, or logically rework your system so that it the header is included when it's not needed. There's not much we can do to help you do that.

Comment: Well, that's sad :/... Because if i remove the header of that loaded page, whe people go directly to that page they won't see it, and that's not good because all their account information is on the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jon's recommendation is the "right way" -- re-architect your system so the header is included only when it's needed.

However, as an (computationally expensive) workaround, in your code that includes the header via AJAX, you can check for the existence of an element that only exists in header.php:

```
//We know that the string "<div id='header'> exists only in header.php
if( $('#header').length < 1 )
{
     //your including header.php code here
}
```